# Incompatible Recaptcha V2 with IE

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I have tried adding meta tag to the header :

But it didn't work.

I tried [this](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/answer/6223838?hl=en) option, still didn't work infact there is no google.com present inside compatible view.

Could anyone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <title>How to Integrate Google “No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA” on Your Website</title> <script src='google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> </head> <body> <form action="" method="post"> <label for="name">Name:</label> <input name="name" required><br /> <label for="email">Email:</label> <input name="email" type="email" required><br /> <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="###"></div> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>How to Integrate Google “No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA” on Your Website</title>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
 
  <body>
 
    <form action="" method="post">
 
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input name="name" required><br />
 
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" required><br />
 
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="###"></div>
 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 
    </form>

Comment: Do you open in as file::// or using web server? And are you sure u use valid source url?

Comment: Yes, i have used valid source url

Answer (score 1):

You should include the necessary JavaScript resource like this:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Besides, set the right site key in the `data-sitekey` attribute.

The result is like this in IE:

[image]

If it still doesn't work in IE 11, you could use F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console.

Comment: Yes, i have set valid key and exact src file in script tag and there is no error in console. Still it is not showing. I am using IE 11.

It is working fine in edge.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src='https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/BT5UwN2jyUJCo7TdbwTYi_58/recaptcha__zh_cn.js'></script>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' defer="" async></script>
  </head>
 <body>
 <form action="" method="post">
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="###"></div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

Comment: @lovishgoel Why you don't add the `https://www.` in the start of `src`? I test in my side if I remove the `https://www.` in `src`, it won't show in IE. Please use this: `src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'`, not this: `src='google.com/recaptcha/api.js'`, then clear browser cache and try again.

Comment: @ Yu Zhou , yes i am doing the same, but didnt work. I just copy and paste in comments so it skips "https:\\www" . I am using forward slashes but when i type here it remove https:// part and create a link www

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Please check the browser mode used by the website and add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` this meta on the html header to make sure the website render in the latest mode in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was loading  loading first time in IE. So, I tried with making url different everytime by appending current datetime.

"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=" + EncodeUrl(SiteKey) + "&time="+CurrTime()

It started working.